# Laravel 5.5 can't connect to database

Tags: php, laravel, database-connection

I have a larvael and I want it to make it in production. I have a server hosting and database on infomaniak.com.

I have upload all my file and I get a SQL timeout error :

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out (SQL: select * from
>   `characters` where `checked` = 1 order by RAND() limit 1)

I have an other Laravel website on infomaniak and don't have this problem. I have check my `.env` file, my `/config/database` file and try `php artisan config:clear` or `php artisan cache:clear`. I also try to dump `DB:connection()` and the connection information are right.

I can connect to my homestead database in local and work fine. But when I try to connect to the SAME database than my other website with the same `.env` file and still have  the timeout error.

How can I fix this ? Are there a way to clear another cache ? Completly lost :/

EDIT :

If i try :

```
if(DB::connection()->getDatabaseName()) {
    echo "Yes! successfully connected to the DB: " . DB::connection()->getDatabaseName();
}
```

The page return `Yes! successfully connected to the DB: db_name`

EDIT 2 :

I just see my hosting server is in PHP 5.6 but it say that's my website is in PHP 7. Really confusing but maybe this informations is important (have another laravel on this server and works like that)

Comment: which query gives you this error ? can run that query  just after checking database connection.

Comment: @C2486 Any queries, in this case it's `Character::inRandomOrder()->where('checked', 1)->limit(1)->first();`

Comment: Are you using multiple database or changing database anywhere ?

Comment: @C2486 Only one and no change, really strange because in another website in production I can connected to the database with same informations, so I think it's a problem in my laravel project

Comment: I hope you have cross checked `.env` file for database connection

Comment: I have verified my .env file mutliple time to be sure (stuck on this for 2 days)

Comment: please check `$users = DB::table('users')->get(); return dd($users);` just after `DB::connection()` check if condition ?

Comment: @C2486 `DB::table('users')->get()` return me `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out (SQL: select * from `users`)`

Comment: the db user have permissions for that database?

Comment: @JoseSilva Yes, if i use the same connection informations in another website I can get and edit data in database

Comment: If you're using laravel, are you sure you really want to check if you're connected into your database?  Have you checked your `.env` file?

Comment: @DessaugesAntoine what version of laravel are you using?

Comment: @JoseSilva LAravel 5.5

Comment: @Jonjie I don't want, the if is just to try to see if i can connect to the db, the timeout error appear at every query. Yeah i have check .env file

Comment: Alright then. Can you also include what query you use? Your exact code, hopefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the php version, if you're using laravel 5.5 then your host must have php 7 installed.

See the oficial docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/installation)